# Ambiguity in limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

What is

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\bigl(\sqrt{\cos^2x-2\sin x+2\sin^2x}\bigr)^{[\sin x]}$

(where $[\,{.}\,]$ denotes greatest integer function) equal to?

I substituted the values directly and that gave me $ 0^1$. This is not an indefinite value and thus the answer should be correct. But the correct answer is $1$. How is that possible?

Comment: You are allowed to substitute the value only if the function is continuous. Otherwise, there is no reason for the limit to be equal to the value.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $x\in [0,\pi]$, $x\neq \frac{\pi}{2}$ $$\left(\sqrt{\cos^2(x)-2\sin(x)+2\sin^2(x)}\right)^{[\sin(x)]}=1.$$

Comment: This is absolutely not true.

Comment: Not at all. It can be $-1$. Also you should add some modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: Now it is correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Let's observe that
$$ \cos^2 x - 2 \sin x + 2\sin^2 x = \sin^2 x -2\sin x + 1 = (\sin x-1)^2  $$
Then $\sqrt{(\sin x - 1)^2} = |\sin(x) - 1| = 1 - \sin x = f(x)$ [let]

Now, we have that
\begin{align*}
[\sin x ] = 0 \quad \text{for any } x \in \left[0, \tfrac{\pi}{2}\right) 
\end{align*}
Hence, as $x \to \pi/2$, $f(x)^0 = 1$.

Comment: Got a gift a gave?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi^+}{2}}\sin(x)=\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi^+}{2}}\sin(x)=1^{-}$$

$$[\sin(x)]=0$$

The expression under root $=0$ (Note that this is not $0$, but $0^+$.)
$$\therefore(\text{something greater than zero})^{0/2}=1$$

In fact, as pointed out by @Surb, this holds good for any $x\in [0,\pi]$, $x\neq \frac{\pi}{2}$ since it again becomes $$(\text{something greater than zero})^{0/2}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The greatest integer function $\lfloor\,{.}\,\rfloor$ is not continuous at $1$, and neither is the composition $f(x)=\lfloor\sin x\rfloor$ at $\pi/2$, so you're not allowed to do direct substitution.

Fix $\delta$ such that $0<\delta<\pi/2$. Then, for $x\in(\pi/2-\delta,\pi/2+\delta)$, we have
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x\ne\pi/2 \\ 1 & x=\pi/2 \end{cases}
$$
so you see that $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}f(x)=0\ne 1=f(\pi/2)$.

Set, for simplicity, $I=(\pi/2-\delta,\pi/2+\delta)$.

The function you're given is well defined in $I\setminus\{\pi/2\}$ because $\cos^2x-2\sin x+2\sin^2x=(1-\sin x)^2$ and this is nonzero for $x\in I\setminus\{\pi/2\}$. On the other hand, $\lfloor\sin x\rfloor=0$ for $x\in I\setminus\{\pi/2\}$ and therefore
$$
\bigl(\textstyle\sqrt{\cos^2x-2\sin x+2\sin^2x}\,\bigr)^{\lfloor\sin x\rfloor}=
\bigl(\sqrt{\cos^2x-2\sin x+2\sin^2x}\,\bigr)^0=1
$$
for $x\in I\setminus\{\pi/2\}$. This means that the limit is $1$.